# Defining columns in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I Have trouble understanding how the defining of variable "j" work.

for (var j = 6; j >= getRow; j++)

What does the "+" means?

And this code below is supposed to give me a message if I'm not clocked out. But it ignore that command. why is that?

```
function clockIn() {

//DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//DEFINE MAIN SHEET
var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");

//FIRST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
var getRow = mainSheet.getRange(1,6);

//INSERT NEW ROW
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
// Shifts all rows down by one
sheet.insertRows(6,1);

for (var j = 6; j >= getRow; j++)

{
  //CHECK CLOCK IN
  if(mainSheet.getRange('B2:B2').getValue() == mainSheet.getRange(j,1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue == '')
  {
    Browser.msgBox('Clock out before you clock in');
    return;
  }

}

//ADD CLOCK IN RECORD

//ADD NAME RECORD
mainSheet.getRange(j,1).setValue(mainSheet.getRange('B2:B2').getValue()).setFontSize(11)

//ADD DATE RECORD
mainSheet.getRange(j,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(11)

//ADD TIME RECORD
mainSheet.getRange(j,3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("kl. hh.mm.ss").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(11);

//ADD NOTE RECORD
mainSheet.getRange(j,6).setValue(mainSheet.getRange('B4:B4').getValue()).setFontSize(11)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not really clear to me what your trying to do with your code perhaps you should just say it words because much of your code is nonsense.

Comment: "_What does the "+" mean?_" Are you asking about the `++` in `j++`? See the JavaScript [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment). If that is new to you, then I recommend a JavaScript introductory tutorial. See also JavaScript ["for" loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: The variable j isn't a true variable, it is just the count of iterations.  It is used for accessing specific items in an array or object.  As andrewjames said, you need to read up on how loops work.